# Como reproduzir um audio na Linguagem C

Tags: c

Se puderem me ajudar, estou fazendo uma Urna Eletrônica na linguagem C, gostaria de colocar aquele barulhinho de voto apos uma pessoa realizar um voto.

Já tenho aquele som no formato .mp3 e .wav, como faco para reproduzir esse som apos um voto? Tem alguma biblioteca especifica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar uma biblioteca, o que irá facilitar o seu desenvolvimento.

- [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/sales/#NonCommercial)
- [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)
- [BASSDLL](http://www.un4seen.com/)

Exemplo com `FMOD`

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "inc/fmod.h"

FSOUND_SAMPLE* handle;

int main ()
{
   // init FMOD sound system
   FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);

   // load and play mp3
   handle=FSOUND_Sample_Load (0,"my.mp3",0, 0, 0);
   FSOUND_PlaySound (0,handle);

   // wait until the users hits a key to end the app
   while (!_kbhit())
   {
   }

   // clean up
   FSOUND_Sample_Free (handle);
   FSOUND_Close();
}
```

*Fonte:* [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/429040/2588695)

Comment: Lembrando que a Bass e Fmod são pagas se for pra uso comercial

Comment: @Bacco bem lembrado, pela pergunta do OP deve ser um projeto de faculdade ou exercício de aprendizado...neste caso para ele não haverá problema.... :)

Comment: acredito que não vá ter problema mesmo, só comentei pq outras pessoas podem ler no futuro, para outros usos.

Comment: @Bacco tranquilo, eu não tinha me atentado para isso... :)

Comment: Onde eu encontro a Fmod, no site deles não tem lugar para baixar a biblioteca, somente FmodStudio

Answer (score 1):

Além dessas que já foram citadas tem essas que fazem reprodução de arquivos WAV com SDL_mixer:

- A SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer)
- SDL_mixer

Veja mais [aqui](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Reproducao-de-arquivos-WAV-com-SDL_mixer-e-linguagem-C).

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando windows tem a função PlaySound.
Exemplo:

```
#include<studio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<mmsystem.h>

int main(){
PlaySound("file.wav",NULL, SND_SYNC);
}
```

Para compilar adicione o `Winmm`, um exemplo com GCC:

```
gcc file.c -o play.exe -lWinmm
```